# How to play dota 2 turbo offline?

Tags: dota-2

I am new to Dota and I liked playing the Turbo mode. Also it is great for trying out new heroes. Is there a way to play Dota turbo offline with bots ?
Also, can I play the other unranked game modes like draft pick and mutation offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Without access to the internet:

You will need to use console commands to set up your game. Enable the console by right-clicking Dota 2 in your steam library, selecting 'properties', then typing "-console" in the 'launch options' field.

Open the console by using the default key of "\"

You can then input the commands below -- or save them as a config file to load up easily next time.

```
con_enable 1                                    //these are all just setup commands
sv_cheats 1                                     
sv_lan 1                                        
sv_hibernate_when_empty 0                       
dota_quit_on_hibernate_after_lobby 0            
dota_quit_after_game 0                          
dota_bot_set_difficulty 3                       //these set bot difficulty: 
dota_bot_match_difficulty 3                         
dota_bot_practice_difficulty 3
dota_bot_practice_gamemode 23                   //game mode selector
dota_bot_match_use_matchmaking 0
dota_bot_practice_start 1
dota_bot_match_solo 1
dota_bot_disable 0
dota_force_gamemode 23
dota_lobby_browser_selected_gamemode 23
dota_heropicker_ap_select_time 999
map dota                                        //actually starts the game
```

Save these commands in a text file, and name it turbo.cfg (or something else .cfg) Place the file in `C:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\game\dota\cfg` 
or wherever your dota installation is located.

Start up dota, open the console, and type `exec turbo` or whatever you named your file. This will start a turbo game with bots for you.

*Credit to [u/aveyo](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/8a9vee/turbo_mode_force_game_mode/) for this information.*

To change the bot difficulty: on the lines with dota_bot_*something*_difficulty, change the number to 0 for passive, 1 for easy, 2 for medium, 3 for hard, and 4 for unfair.

This will always put you on radiant team. I don't know how to allow selection of team.

Also, I tried mutation mode (game mode 24) but it did not seem to work. Hero picker screen said mutation, but nothing seemed different.

---

### If you *do* have access to the internet

use the **Custom Lobby** Feature in the Play Dota tab.

[image]

**Edit** the options at the bottom:

[image]

Select **Turbo** mode (or captain's mode, all pick, mutation, whatever), and **Fill empty Slots with Bots**. You can customize bot difficulty separately for each team.

[image]

### Start it up, and you're ready to go!

Comment: Thanks @Roijan Eskor. Is there a way I can do this while being offline ? I can't create custom lobbies while being offline.

Comment: @VishnuVS I think so. Will test this when I get home this evening

Comment: @VishnuVS Added information to the answer.

Comment: sorry for being REALLY late :) , it worked. Thank you.